# Inconsistent handling of accents in binary fulltext search in MariaDB

Tags: full-text-search, mariadb

I am puzzled how MariaDB fulltext search handles accents. I find it inconsistent and I would like to understand why.

To illustrate my problem lets create a testing table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `fulltext_test` (
  `title` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci NOT NULL,
  FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=277 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_czech_ci
```

I defined `collate` because in real-life table I need to perform sorting according that column so I really want `utf8_czech_ci`.

Lets insert one row:

```
INSERT INTO `fulltext_test` VALUES ('klíč');
```

And now test how it behaves. This is an expected behaviour:

```
> SELECT * FROM `fulltext_test` WHERE MATCH (`title`) AGAINST ("klíč" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
+--------+
| title  |
+--------+
| klíč   |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And this is what puzzles me. From the first result (search for "klíc") I would say fulltext search is accute-sensitive, but the second result (search for "klič", notice the subtle difference: **í** instead of **i**) proves it is not.

```
> SELECT * FROM `fulltext_test` WHERE MATCH (`title`) AGAINST ("klíc" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
Empty set (0.00 sec)

> SELECT * FROM `fulltext_test` WHERE MATCH (`title`) AGAINST ("klič" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
+--------+
| title  |
+--------+
| klíč   |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why is this happening? How can I configure it?

Comment: MyISAM or InnoDB?  What version?

Comment: @RickJames "$ mysql --version" prints "mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.21-MariaDB". And it is InnoDB.

Comment: Can you provide a few more Czech words, and which should or should not compare?

Comment: @RickJames It looks like it is not about words but characters. E.g. these all return true: select 'd' = 'ď' collate utf8_czech_ci, 'n' = 'ň', 'e' = 'ě' collate utf8_czech_ci collate utf8_czech_ci; but these return false: select 'r' = 'ř' collate utf8_czech_ci, 'c' = 'č' collate utf8_czech_ci, 'z' = 'ž' collate utf8_czech_ci, 'š' = 's' collate utf8_czech_ci; So 'vek' = 'věk', but 'rek' != 'řek' (under czech collate).

Comment: As I see it now, it must be some mistake in definition of collate utf8_czech_ci. Because I do not see any reason why ň and č should be handled differently…

Comment: There is already a reported bug that probably causes the problem: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-11199 It might be fixed in the future releases (~ MariaDB-10.3)?

Comment: [_This_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html) lists the equivalences for the various collations.  In general, any collation other than `_bin` will treat accented chars equal to the unaccented variant.  Ditto for case folding.  This _probably_ leads to "errors" in comparing words in `FULLTEXT`.

Comment: And, yes, consonants with a 'caron' are treated as separate letters.  Also `ch` acts like a letter between `h` and `i`.  There may be a fix coming in MySQL 8.0 with collation `utf8mb4_cs_0900...`

Comment: @RickJames But even if I use utf8_bin I do not get "consistent" results. By "consistent" I mean always "acute and carons insensitive" or "always sensitive". You see some solution, Rick? Preferably without patching anything, that is error prone…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the existing collations, I don't think there is a way to do either of these for Czech:

- Always be insensitive to acute and caron accents, or
- Alwasy be sensitive to them.

Here is a clumsy workaround:

Add another column

```
search TEXT NOT NULL
```

then put into `search` a copy of the text to search, but with all the accents stripped off.  Or at least all the carons stripped off.  You can use a tedious set of `REPLACE(...)` functions to do so.

Then have *that* column have the `FULLTEXT` index, but the original column is what you display.

Or...

It *may* suffice for `search` to be a copy of the original column, except for the collation:

```
search TEXT COLLATION utf8_bin NOT NULL
```

(and have `FULLTEXT(search)`)